# Adding a Topic ID to a Google Classroom assignment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm trying to create an assignment using Google Apps script and place it under a topic that is also created in the same script. I have no problem creating an assignment when no topicId is specified, but as soon as I try to specify a topicId , I receive the following error when I run the script: *API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.create failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Test Topic"*

Here is my code:

```
function makeStuff() {

  var topic = { 
    name: "Test Topic"
  };
  Classroom.Courses.Topics.create(topic, "46088716060");               

  var TWS1 =  {
    title: "Test Worksheet 1",
    state: "DRAFT",
    materials: [
      {
        driveFile:{
        driveFile: {
          id: "1REOs1RYtyVTX67VnJezjWf-wm7HqDVexeaeiQL3-HvM", 

        },
        shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
        }

      }
      ],
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT",
    topicId: {
    name: "Test Topic"
    }

  };

  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(TWS1, "46088716060") 
}
```

Is it possible to reference the topicId by name, or assign the topicId number that is created in the script to a variable that can be referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a topic, you only need to supply a name (the topic name is not its id, only the API can generate ids). The Classroom API then creates the topic, which it returns as an object with the `topicId` property defined on it, as seen below;

```js
var courseId = "46088716060";
var topicName = "Test Topic";

var topic = Classroom.Courses.Topics.create({name:topicName}, courseId);
var topicId = topic.topicId;
```

You then use that `topicId` when creating coursework.