# How can I get a Topic ID using Topic Name in Google Classroom?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm using Google Apps Script to create an assignment in a few Google Classrooms under a few previously created Topics in each Classroom. I know the Topic Names, but not the IDs - Is there a way that I can create the assignments using the Names to get the IDs?

Here's what I'm trying (but topicID ends up being null instead of the actual ID):

```
function addAssignments() {
  var courseIds = ['100000000000','100000000001'];
  var topicNames = ['Topic1','Topic2'];
  for (var i = 0; i < courseIds.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < topicNames.length; j++) {
      var topicId = topicNames[j].topicID; 
      var exec = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({
            title: "My Assignment",
            topicId: topicId,
            workType: "ASSIGNMENT",
        }, courseIds[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Looked at [Adding a Topic ID to a Google Classroom assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772918/adding-a-topic-id-to-a-google-classroom-assignment) (But this is making a new Topic in the process of making the Assignment - my Topics are already made), and [Is there an example of the Classroom.Courses.Topics.get so I can call Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create with an existing topicId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724676/is-there-an-example-of-the-classroom-courses-topics-get-so-i-can-call-classroom/60726443#60726443) (But, when I tried [courses.topics.get()](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics/get), I couldn't figure out a quick way to get just the ID I need out of the response - Problem could also be my iteration or something, so I've included that in my code example).

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén Added - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the topic ID from the topic name, and create the courseWork using the retrieved topic ID using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- At `var topicId = topicNames[j].topicID;`, you try to retrieve `topicID` from an array of `var topicNames = ['Topic1','Topic2'];`.
- In order to retrieve the topic IDs, the method of "courses.topics.list" is used.
- In this modification, I used the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the topic ID list.
  2. Create an object for searching the topic ID from the topic name.
  3. Create the courseWork using the retrieved topic ID.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function addAssignments() {
  var courseIds = ['100000000000','100000000001'];
  var topicNames = ['Topic1','Topic2'];
  for (var i = 0; i < courseIds.length; i++) {

    var topics = Classroom.Courses.Topics.list(courseIds[i]).topic;  // Added
    var topicObj = topics.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.name]: e.topicId}), {});  // Added

    for (var j = 0; j < topicNames.length; j++) {

      var topicId = topicObj[topicNames[j]];  // Added

      var exec = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({
        title: "My Assignment",
        topicId: topicId,
        workType: "ASSIGNMENT",
      }, courseIds[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that Google Classroom API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

#### Reference:

- [Method: courses.topics.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics/list)